# Salesforce Hotkeys for Chrome

Tags: security, chrome, keyboard

Does anyone know if there are any **security (or other) concerns** related to this Chrome plugin?

Link:    [Salesforce Hotkeys (BETA)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-hotkeys-beta/hkpmdgakkflkddmiffelfaokkgoamlil)

My manager is interested in implementing it, but we both want to do due diligence to make sure they're not capturing keywtrokes (passwords, data, et al).  Otherwise, for some users, it would be a great utility (especially those who are **keyboard-fans** / anti-mouse).

The creator has a longstanding [Twitter](https://twitter.com/prafullanpatil) account and looks legitimate to me, plus the version control listing on the plugin's page as well.

Thanks!

Comment: You might also ask on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/), they're more likely to take a deeper dive into looking for red flags (security-wise).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [CRX Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin?hl=en) on the Chrome Web Store. It lets you view the source of extensions.

All Chrome Extensions undergo a security review before publishing. This process is known as ‘Enhanced Item Validation’ (EIV), and is a series of rigorous checks that examines a plugin’s code and its behavior when installed, in order to identify malware. Read more about it [here.](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/3kpAu4VcP5E)

However, if you're not sure about the security of an extension, it's best not to use it, especially when sensitive data is at stake. It's important to weigh the pros/cons in situations like this.